# modify request before validation

Tags: python, validation, flask, wtforms

I have a registration form:

```
class AddUserForm(Form):
    email = StringField(_('Email'), [validators.DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', [validators.DataRequired()])
    forename = StringField('Forename', [validators.DataRequired()])
    surname = StringField('Surname', [validators.DataRequired()])
    address = TextAreaField('Address', [validators.DataRequired()])
    join_date = DateField('Join Date', [validators.DataRequired()])
```

and view like this:

```
@app.route('user/add/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add():
    #  here I need to modify request.form
    form = AddUserForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        user = User(email=request.form['email'])
        form.populate_obj(user)
        user.set_password(request.form['password'])
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'message': 'thanks for registration',
                        'status': 'success'})
    return render_template('user/form.html', form=form)
```

and the problem is when i try to validate this form.

form.validate() returns false with request.form['join_date'] value so I have to convert date field to gregorian date first.

I thought if I could anyhow modify the request.form before passing it to addUserForm(), then my form.validate() would not return false.

but I couldn't since it is an ImmutableMultiDict. 
I want to know if its possible to make a copy of request.form which is not Immutable or any other way to modify request before validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I don't have to modify request.form. I can modify the form which I passed request.form to it.

```
from jdatetime import datetime

def add():
    form = AddUserForm(request.form)
    # can modify the form with form.<NAME>.data
    form.phone.data = datetime.strptime(request.form['join_date'], '%Y/%m/%d').date().togregorian()
    # and validate it then
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        # do stuff
```